# How do I add dynamic metadata in Angular4

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an angular4 blogging app which needs dynamic metadata for SEO. 
My service (BlogService) delivers JSON data from a PHP server.
e.g.

```
{"ID":"168","title":"HTML Src Test","description":"testing the html thingy in angular","content":"<h1>Hello, World ... This is a heading.<\/h1>\n<p><img title=\"test\" src=\"https:\/\/i.stack.imgur.com\/ipOIT.png\" alt=\"test\" width=\"20%\" \/><\/p>\n<pre class=\"prettyprint\">code code <br \/>function(){<br \/>console.log(\"hello\");<br \/>alert(\"hello\");<br \/>}<\/pre>\n<p>&nbsp;<\/p>","date":"26th Apr 2017","slug":"html-src-test","imagepath":"","category":"Testy Test McTest","ttr":1,"comcount":0}
```

This is then interpreted and displayed in the usual Angular way (e.g.
 {{post.title}})

BlogService:

```
getPost(slug: string): Promise<Post> {
        const url = `${this.blogUrl}?id=${slug}`;
        console.log(this.http.get(url).toPromise().then(response => response.json()));

        return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as Post)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

BlogpostComponent:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
}
getData() {
    this.route.params
        .switchMap((params: Params) => this.service.getPost(params['slug']))
        .subscribe(post => this.post = post);
}
```

How do I pass the data from this http Request and display it in the meta tags in the HTML ?

Thanks

Comment: Meta tags are not even important anymore (exept for the musts) as google started focusing on actual content within the page than meta tag title and descriptions. Just make sure to have a good links and content in the page and MAKE SURE your URL don't suck and is readable. Other than that Anguar universe should take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming we realize that this means nothing for SEO without [universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) (Server-side rendering) etc. And also that we are using v4+.

You can handle meta with platform-browser which has `Title` and `Meta` etc.

```
import { Title, Meta, MetaDefinition } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...

constructor(
  private _meta: Meta,
  private _title: Title   

...

this._title.setTitle('foo');

...

let meta: MetaDefinition[] = [
  { name: 'application-name', content: 'foo' },
  { name: 'description', content: 'bar' }
];

this._meta.addTags(meta);
```

**Update:**
So yes in your case you could add based on the response.

```
 .subscribe((post) => {
     this.post = post; 
     this._title.setTitle( this.post.title ); 
 });
```

For cleanliness I would create a separate 'service.method' like 'setPageMeta()', which can be used to handle route.data or http response.

Comment: Thanks for the above,
How would I pass data from the component into the meta data?
Would "this.post.title" work (or similar)?

Comment: I just put the relevant bits, you would add the methods / events (like router/navigationEnd) or when some data returns.  You will need to search for the elements in console to verify.